# How to reinitialise angular

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular app which uses many services to hold user data. However, when I sign out and sign in another user again, because these services are singleton and didn't get chance to initialise, therefore, these data which is for the previous user still there.

What I can do is emit a 'signed-in' message after sign-in , and write a listen in each services to re-initialise, but that is too much effort.

So I　am thinking if there is a way to re-initialise all services or the whole angular app. I know redirect will do this job, but is there a better way?

Thanks,
Ron

Comment: You could do a page reload, if you're looking for a quick and dirty way to clear the service data that is in memory. If you're using ngRoute, this might work: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#reload

Comment: I am using ui-router, and I tried to put "reload:true" into $routerProvider settings, but seems not working, I will look into this very soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways I can think of to accomplish this,

1. All your services that need resetting have a reset function so that when the user signs out, the reset function gets executed on user signout
2. The sign out function broadcasts an event that causes all necessary services to reset

I'm more in favour of #1, but you can even take it a step further and create a service that executes all the reset functionality so you would ever need to execute one function to reset your data.

eg.

```
function SomeController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.click = function() {
        ResetService.resetAll();
    }

}

app.factory('ResetService', function(UserService, EmailService) {
    var resetAll = function() {
         UserService.reset();
         EmailService.reset();
    };

    return {
        resetAll: resetAll
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create a single Cache object (using Angular's [$cacheFactory](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory) service) that is shared between each of your services to store data. Then, when the user signs out, you would just call the `.removeAll()` method on the cache.

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .factory('userDataCache', userDataCacheFactory)
    .factory('userService', userServiceFactory)
    .factory('authService', authServiceFactory);

function userDataCacheFactory($cacheFactory) {
    return $cacheFactory('userData');
}

function userServiceFactory(userDataCache) {
    var key = 'userService';
    var service = {
        setUserData: function(data) {
            userDataCache.put(key, data);
        },
        getUserData: function() {
            userDataCache.get(key);
        }
    };
}

function authServiceFactory(userDataCache) {
    var service = {
        logOut: function() {
            userDataCache.removeAll();
        }
    };
}
```